# Standard API for rendering a date form

Tags: date-time, forms

I'm hoping to enhance an existing plugin's setting page by adding an 'end date' form. I know how to add text and other form fields but was wondering if there is standard function that will render a year/data/time form. No sense in re-inventing the wheel.

Thanks for all tips.

Answer (score 1):

Could this work for you?

```
<link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { $("#thedate").val(dateText); } }); 
    });
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top;">
            <h3>End Date</h3>
        </td>
    <td>
        <ul>
            <li><p>(Pick a date from the calendar below)</p></li>
            <li>
                <div style="margin-bottom:5px;" type="text" id="datepicker"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                Date Selected: <input type="text" id="thedate" name="date"/> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks rman.

I was actually looking for a standard framework but this script method will do just nicely.

[newb]

Comment: lol, no idea why this was voted down -1; seems prefectly good code to me.

Comment: I concur (why voted down), the suggested code worked nicely.